# Numpy dot product returning either a np.array or a float

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Since I am new to Numpy and Linear Algebra, I am confused about these results below. I heard that matrices cannot be multiplied like in the Example B which is [1 x 2] x [1 x 2]. But somehow this still works. Only thing I could catch is that the return type is different. I am wondering how does example B work in Numpy and how the return type is different.

A) With extra brackets: [[2],[-10]]

```
np.array([1, 1]).dot(np.array([[2], [-10]]))

# array([-8])
```

B) Without additional brackets: [2, -10]

```
np.array([1, 1]).dot(np.array([2, -10]))

# -8
```

Comment: Where did you hear this?

Comment: Whoever told you that this multiplication isn't possible was wrong.

Comment: I encountered this in a lecture I saw on the internet

Comment: It appears that you're looking for a tutorial in the definitions of matrix operations.  This is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You don't actually have any 1x2 matrices. The ones you think are 1x2 are just 2 - they're one-dimensional. There's no implicit length-1 axis.

Comment: @MattLee If you can tell us which lecture, maybe someone could tell you either “stop listening to that guy, he’s an idiot” or “here’s what he meant, and here’s why you got it wrong”, but without knowing what you watched except that it was something on the internet, it’s hard to say anything.

Comment: Matrix multiplication is normally defined for 2d arrays (matrices).  However `np.dot` handles 1d arrays as a special case(s), modeled on the mathematical `dot` product of vectors.  It also has rules for 3d (and higher) arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first example is a length-2 vector inner product with a 2x1 matrix, which results in a length-1 vector.

The second example is a length-2 vector inner product with a length-2 vector, which result in a scalar.

These are the expected results for inner products. You can read more in the [np.dot documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)